# Solr Data Config Error, Open quote is expected for attribute "driver"

Tags: solr

I have a postgres data-config file.

```
<dataConfig>
  <dataSource driver=”org.postgresql.Driver” url=”jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/mydb” user=”user” password=”pw” />
...
</dataConfig>
```

But when I run it, it shows error

```
Data Config problem: Open quote is expected for attribute "driver" associated with an element type "dataSource".
```

What's the problem here. is driver information that I put wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your quotes are wrong.

`”` and `"` are not the same kind of quotes (see the different presentation). Only `"` is a valid double quote in an XML file (and in most/all programming contexts).

The examples in your config file seems to have been mangled by a blog or a text editor on the way.

Comment: This blocked me for hours, Thank you.